# How to add an sObject to a sublislist?

Tags: apex, soql

I generated a list from a soql query, and try to add an sobject to it. The following code compiles, but it's not adding it, also, I'm not seeing an issue in the debug log. what's going on here? anyway around it, or recommendations on what i should do?

```
List<Account> accts= [
    Select Name, (select firstName, lastName from Contacts)
    FROM Account
    Limit 10
];
Contact c = new Contact(firstName = 'Marc', lastName = 'B', AccountId = accts[0].Id);
accts[0].contacts.add(c);
system.debug(json.serialize(accts[0].contacts));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`accts[0].contacts` returns a list of Contacts, it's like a getter method.You can not add a contact into it directly.You have to take those contacts in another list and then add new contact in that list.

Like this:

```
List<Contact> conList = acc[0].contacts;
conList.add(c);
```

As @sfdcdox has suggested in comments you can copy `acc[0].contacts` list into another list by iterating it.Maybe this could save you from some issues on orgs with large data.

Comment: Actually, your code won't quite work, because Contacts is basically read-only (it's a magic list!). Instead, you can clone it first, like `Contact[] conList = acc[0].Contacts.clone();` The cloned list can have more records added to it.

Comment: @sfdcfox Really!!! But it is working for me.would you elaborate this read only part for me? I tried my code on developer console and i'm seeing the new contact added into list.

Comment: Hmm, it used to not work before, but maybe they've changed it since then. Regardless, it does have some extra logic that kicks in when there's more than a few hundred children, so you'll get errors like "list too large for direct assignment" when that happens. I've taken to using alternative means of dealing with child relationships since then, usually by way of a for-each loop and adding them to a new list.

Comment: @sfdcfox Hmm...I think i have run this code on some org with large data...but i didn't get any such error...Not sure maybe you are right.Added your point in the answer.

Comment: I just tested it, and indeed it seems to work differently now (from my recollections, at any rate). So, I've learned something new today, and I'm pretty sure this wasn't in a release note anywhere.

Comment: @sfdcfox Sounds Great :)

Comment: @sfdcfox does this mean we can now mock Selector layer Soql w/ subqueries using SObjects?   This would be outstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You should query account then Create contacts using `AccountId` and then query again. Adding contact your way is not correct approach.

See sample below:

```
List<Account> accts= [
    Select Name, (select firstName, lastName from Contacts)
    FROM Account
    Limit 10
];

if(accts.size()>0)
{
   Contact c = new Contact(firstName = 'Marc', lastName = 'B', AccountId =      accts[0].Id);
insert c;
}
```

Since you have provided `AccountID` is will be automatically associated to Account. If you want this as a List just query it again and you will get the new Contact recently created:

```
List<Account> accts= [
    Select Name, (select firstName, lastName from Contacts)
    FROM Account
    Limit 10
];
```

Also if you want only Contact for the Account then query would be:

```
List<Contact> conList = [select firstName, lastName from Contact WHERE Account id =:accts[0].Id];
```

Note: Make sure Account has records other wise exception will occur as you are passing index number (`0`).